# Flurry appMetrics API

Tags: c#, httpwebrequest, flurry

I am receiving a "The remote server returned an error: (400) Bad Request." when I try the following code.

If I enter the URL directly into my browser's address bar, it will return the correct XML file.

I verified the logic of my code using the commented out "// String url = "http://www.weather.gov/xml/current_obs/KDFW.xml";" and it returns an XML dump.

Again, the issue is a browser address bar will return the xml dump, but calling the api in code returns a 400 error.

> String url =
>   "http://api.flurry.com/eventMetrics/Event?apiAccessCode=YHJBA13CSKTMS6XHTM6M&apiKey=6XQY729FDU1CR9FKXVZP&startDate=2011-2-28&endDate=2011-3-1&eventName=Tip%20Calculated";
>              // String url = "http://www.weather.gov/xml/current_obs/KDFW.xml";
>
> ```
>         HttpWebRequest webreq = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
>         WebResponse res = webreq.GetResponse();
>         using (Stream stream = res.GetResponseStream())
>             {
>                  StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(stream, Encoding.UTF8);
>                           while (reader.Peek() >= 0)
>                               {
>                                       memoEdit1.Text += reader.ReadLine() + System.Environment.NewLine;
>                               }
>             }
> ```

I've been wrestling with this issue for 3 days.  Any help is appreciated.

Comment: I can't answer my own question, but by adding the following, my problem has been resolved. "request.Accept = "application/xml";"  Hope this helps someone else.

Answer (score 3):

I've added the following and it has fixed my problem.

```
request.Accept = "application/xml";
```

Hope this helps someone else.